# Do I have collinearity?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, multicollinearity, glmm, post-hoc

this is my first post on this forum. I'm a masters student and have a question regarding my experimental setup. I collected arthropods in six vineyards, each vineyard with two plots (a treatment and a control plot) during different months (April/June/July). I sampled two habitats (grape/grass) per vineyard, and I also collected data on vegetation cover (categorical variable, 5 levels: very low - very high) and richness (continuous variable) in these vineyards.

I ran a model (negative binomial glmm) with arthropod abundance as the response variable, and habitat, month, treatment*month interaction and vegetation cover and richness as the fixed factors. I included the vineyard as a random factor. In the model below, all factors are significant.

```
Total_arthropods ~  Treatment*Month  + Habitat+ Veg_covercat + Veg_rich +(1|Vineyard)
```

From my data I can see a clear positive relationship between arthropod abundance and vegetation cover - there are more arthropods in the very high level of vegetation cover.

Before running a model, I checked if there was collinearity via GVIF, and all values were <2, which as far as I know, should indicate that I had no collinearity. However, some of the levels of vegetation cover are never represented in some of my treatment*month combinations (see picture below: number of observations per level, from table function). 
[image]

I did a post-hoc test (lsmeans) to test for significant pairwise comparisons of the interaction between treatment and month. Some of the results seemed unreliable (I found a significant difference even if the average abundances were very close and the SDs very large). Because of the table above, I suspect that there may be some issue with the inclusion of vegetation cover in the model. In fact, when I remove this factor, and run the post-hoc again, the suspicious p-values change dramatically from very significant to non-significant at all (which makes more sense).

Is this an indication that I have collinearity between vegetation cover and some of the other factors?

Thanks a lot!

(I am using R version 3.5.1 on a Windows computer)